# JPA2 Optimistick Lock

Tags: java, spring, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, optimistic-locking

Hi I'm struggling with Optimistick Lock on JPA2 and I have no more ideas why is it occurring.
My case is that I'm running multiple threads but there is one entity in the DB which stores progress. Which means that different threads are trying to update this entity during execution to make possible to see the progress by user.

I have a methods `addAllItems` and `addDone`. Both of methods are used to update the entity by several threads and I'm displaying the result by showing `(done/allItems)*100`.

Methods were simple at the beginning

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void addAllItems(Long id, Integer items){
    Job job = jobDao.findById(id);
    job.setAll(job.getAll() + items);

    jobDao.merge(job);
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void addDone(Long id, Integer done){
    Job job = jobDao.findById(id);
    job.setDone(job.getDone() + done);

    jobDao.merge(job);
}
```

When I realized that Optimistic Lock is occurring I changed both methods by adding synchronized to the signature. It has no effect so I added refresh (from entity manager) to make sure that I'm having current version. It also made no difference. I also added manual flush at the end, but still nothing better...

Here is final version of method (`addAllItems` is pretty much the same, only difference is in setter):

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public synchronized void addDone(Long id, Integer done){
    Job job = jobDao.findById(id);
    job = jobDao.refresh(job);
    job.setDone(job.getDone() + done);

    jobDao.merge(job);
    jobDao.flush();
}
```

Where the `jobDao.refresh` method is just calling refresh on `entityManager`.
I'm using eclipselink 2.40.

What else can I check?
I'm out of ideas at the moment...

Comment: I'm working on it, but deadline is very close so I am looking for help  of more experienced people. I thought that's the reason why stackoverflow was created. If you don't want to answer just do not respond please.

Comment: Perhaps you should use pessimistic lock on job?

Comment: On what entity does the error occur ? Really `Job` ? Could you show what are `all` and `done` in `Job`

Comment: @SergeBallesta
Error occurs on the Job entity. all and done are just Integers.

Here is a log line:


`javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Exception [EclipseLink-5006] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.OptimisticLockException
Exception Description: The object [com.hg.entity.Job@98] cannot be updated because it has changed or been deleted since it was last read. 
Class> com.hg.entity.Job Primary Key> 152`

Comment: You should first ensure that you do use the transactional proxy (look into stacktrace), and then use a pessimistic lock

Comment: There is a proxy:
`[com.hg.service.JobServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$188a7e8c.invoke(<generated>)
 at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)`

I've never worked with Pesimistic Lock before... Is it possible to use it only for one entity (Job in that case)?

Comment: How is the entityManager obtained within the DAO, and how synchronous are your calls?  Optimistic locking prevents changes in addAllItems and addDone from occurring simultaneously, so I'm not sure why you want to avoid it.  The point of optimistic locking is to give you that indication that your change is occurring on stale data - you then have the option to retry your transaction.  If you switch to using synchronous blocks or pessimistic locking, you are slowing down and gating your application.  Both options have merits; you need to look at your use case and not just try to avoid exceptions

Answer (score 1):

As you are sure that you are using a proxy (I assume you correctly configured the `PlatformTransactionManager`), you could try to use an explicit pessimistic lock inside the transaction - normally you should not need to do so, but if it fixes the problem ...

I suppose that in your dao, you have something like :

```
Job job = EntityManager.find(Job.class, jobId);
```

To force a pessimistic lock, just change it to :

```
Job job = EntityManager.find(Job.class, jobId, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

As you just do load, modify, store and commit, it might be a correct use case for pessimistic locking.